# Model-based Quantifier Instantiation and the St1 fragment of many-sorted logic

Tags: z3

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10799108/1211793) on Z3's Model-based
Quantifier Instantiation (MBQI) and the stratified sorts fragment (thanks
again to Leonardo de Moura for the quick answer).

In their paper on decidable fragments of many-sorted logic [Abadi et
al., Decidable fragments of many-sorted logic, LPAR 2007], the authors
describe a fragment St1 of many-sorted logic that is decidable with a
finite model property.

This fragment requires the sorts to be stratified and the formula F to be in (skolemized) prenex normal form as described in the Z3
documentation, but allows an additional atomic formula

> y in Im[f]

to occur in F, which is a "shorthand" for

> exists x1 : A1, ..., xn : An . y = f(x1,...,xn)

where f is a function with a signature f : A1 x ... x An -> B, and f must be the only function with range B. Thus, the St1 fragment allows (in a very restricted way) to violate the stratification, e.g., in order to assert that f is surjective.

I am not sure if this could be an open research question:
Does someone know whether the MBQI decision procedure for Z3 is complete
for the St1 fragment? Will Z3 produce (theoretically) either SAT or
UNSAT for F after a finite time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, one clarification, in principle, MBQI can decide the stratified multi-sorted fragment. The justification is given in Section 4.1 of http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/ci.pdf (*). However, Z3 4.0 does not support implement the additional rules suggested in Section 4.1. So, Z3 4.0, may fail (return `unknown`) on formulas that are in this fragment. I just want to make clear a distinction between the algorithm and the actual implementation using the current Z3.

Regarding your question, yes MBQI framework can decide the stratified formulas containing the expanded predicate `y in Im[f]`. I'm assuming this predicate occurs only positively.
That is, we do not have `not y in Im[f]` which is equivalent to

`forall x1:A1, ...,xn:An. y != f(x1, ... xn)`

If `y in Im[f]` occurs only positively, then it can be expanded, and after skolemization we have a ground formula of the form `y = f(k1, ..., kn)`. 
MBQI is still a decision procedure because the set `F*` defined in (*) will still be finite. `F*` may become infinite only if the stratification is broken inside of a universal formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. I could write the ground formula F* for my St1 examples, and it is indeed finite :)